# How would I write this as javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel

I have a forumula that is:

```
=ROUNDUP((amtfin-fv*(1+rate) ^ n),2)
```

Does anybody know how I would convert this to Javascript? So far I already have:

```
Math.round((amtfin-fv*(1 + rate)-n), 2);
```

It's the ^ part i'm struggling with really.

Any help would be appreciated as always.

Comment: [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)?

Comment: Nope tried that, sorry forgot to mentioned in the post.

Comment: What do you mean by "nope"? Are you saying `Math.pow` doesn't do what it claims? Or are you saying that `^` in excel isn't equivalent?

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't do what it claims, I'm saying that I've tried that and it didn't work, however I may have used it in the wrong position in the line.

Comment: @Codarz360 Could you include in your question how you used `Math.pow`, then? That's what you need to use. Saying "nope" and "it didn't work" doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `Math.pow(number, power)`.

```
  Math.pow(2, 4) // => 16


   Math.round((amtfin - (fv * Math.pow(1+rate, n)))/100)
```

Comment: This is the full Excel formula - =ROUNDUP(((amtfin-fv*(1+rate)^-n)/(((1-(1+rate)^-n)/rate)*(1+rate*advarr))*uplift+accfee),2) I've already converted some to Javascript this part "=ROUNDUP(((amtfin-fv*(1+rate)^-n)" it's the next section I'm struggling with - "(((1-(1+rate)^-n)/rate)*(1+rate*advarr))*uplift+accfee)" pretty sure it's the math.pow again but not entirely sure.

Comment: function roundup(val, ndig) {
 return (val > 0 ? Math.ceil : Math.floor)(val*Math.pow(10,ndig))/Math.pow(10,ndig);
}

function calculate(amtfin, fv, rate, n, advarr, uplift, accfee) {
    var val1 = amtfin - fv * Math.pow(1 + rate, -n);
    var val2 = ((1-Math.pow(1+rate,-n))/rate)*(1+rate*advarr);
    var val = val1 / val2 * uplift
    val += accfee;
    return roundup(val,2);
}